# How to count specific column in psql?

Tags: postgresql

Firstly, I'm so sorry with the basic question. I want to sum child data and count number of transaction as the following field:

- amount (totally)
- level (totalLevel)
- number of trasanction (Transaction Times)

I have 2 table which related. One user has many transaction.

1. User Table

   - id
   - name
2. Transaction Table

   - id
   - user_id
   - amount
   - level

**Here is query that I have test. But, it seem not work as expected:**

```
const query = `
      SELECT
        u.*,
        't.amount',
        't.level'
        COUNT('t.amountDiffCents') as "numberOfTransaction",
        SUM('t.level') as "Total Level",
        COUNT(u.*) OVER () as "totalCount"
      FROM "LoyaltyUser" as u
      INNER JOIN "Transaction" as t ON u.id = 't.userId'
      GROUP BY u.id
      LIMIT $limit
      OFFSET $offset;
    `;
```

Thank beforehand.

Comment: How is `numberOfTransaction` meant to compare to `totalCount` ? If they mean different things then please rename them so their meaning is apparent.

Comment: Sorry. I mistaken on this. I have correct it. Please check again

Comment: @Dai Yea surely. I want to count transaction times.

Comment: But what does "count transaction times" mean? I don't see timestamps in your schema... In situations like these you should avoid using ambiguous terms like "times" to refer to "occurrences" or "rows".

Comment: BTW, you should never use `LIMIT/OFFSET` without an `ORDER BY` - otherwise your results will be in undefined order. PostgreSQL _should_ be giving you a warning for that - you're not using MySQL, I hope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate the Transactions table separately, then JOIN Users only afterwards:

```
SELECT
    u.*,
    agg.txn_count,
    agg.sum_level
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            t.user_id,
            COUNT(*) AS txn_count,
            SUM( t.level ) AS sum_level
        FROM
            transaction AS t
        GROUP BY
            t.user_id
    ) AS agg

    INNER JOIN loyalty_user AS u ON
        u.uid = agg.user_id
```

Strictly speaking (ISO SQL) it is not possible to meaningfully include the total number of all `transaction` rows in this single result-set (at least, not without having a repeating value in every row, ew). Instead that can be trivially performed by application code - or use a second query in the same batch.

Comment: May I know, what's agg refer to?

Comment: @ChantySok `agg` is the name of the _derived table_ from the inner `SELECT t.user_id, ...` query.

Comment: Thank @Dai. You saved my day. But, May I ask you that I use this query to get list of user. If it's not match between user and transaction table. it's will not show data. Can I set if there's is no child data return all user and set **count=0,sum_level=0**?